# Referencing cell only by column name in Excel 2010 VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba, named-ranges

In Excel 2010, I need to go through a data table row by row and manipulate the data in VBA.

My original function reads like this:

```
Private Function GetValue(ByVal myRange As Excel.Range, ByVal strCol As String) As String
    Dim myCell As Object
    Set myCell = myRange.Cells(, strCol) 
    GetValue = myCell.Value 
End Function
```

I call it like this:

```
GetValue(myRow, "AE")
```

`myRow` is an Excel.Range representing a row.
`"AE"` is the column index.

I want to convert to use column names instead of column indexes because users may choose to add or remove columns in the future. I identified a range of cells as a table in Excel, named the table, and chose unique column names.

This means I would now call the function by using:

```
GetValue(myRow, "column_name")
```

but I can't find examples where I can specify only the column name without also specifying the row.

Is this even feasible?

Comment: If you don't want to specify the row, how will Excel/VBA know what row you're trying to manipulate?

Comment: Because I'm passing the row as a parameter to the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code [from other answer](https://superuser.com/a/875880/263488) didn't compile for me, but it allowed me to do some further research.

Inspired by [How do i loop an excel 2010 table by using his name & column reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495678)
and [How to loop though a table and access row items by their column header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070123), I ended up using:

```
Private Function GetValue(ByVal myRange As Excel.Range, ByVal strCol As String) As String
    GetValue = myRange.Columns(myRange.ListObject.ListColumns(strCol).Range.Column).Value
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
Public Function GetValue2(ByVal myRow As Long, ByVal strColumnName As String) As String
    Dim myCell As Object

    Set myCell = Cells(myRow, Range(strColumnName).Column)
    GetValue2 = myCell.Value
End Function
```

In this example, I "named" column **B** "qwerty"

[image]

Please note there will be potential *volatility* problems with this function.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by volatility problems?

Comment: I mean that if you change the contents of column **B,** the function is not smart enough to know it is necessary to recalculate itself.

Comment: Actually, having the function knowing it is necessary to recalculate is not part of my requirements. But thanks for thinking ahead. :)